# Como enviar contenido de una tabla html a un formulario de otra pagina con javascript y jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

Estimados como se podría capturar el dato de una tabla hecha en jsp y mostrarlo con javascript en un formulario de otra pagina?
Lo he intentado pero dentro de la misma pagina pero cuando quiero mostrarlo en otra pagina no se visualiza.

el código de ejemplo que estoy usando es el siguiente como para explicar el tema de manera simple.

```
<table id="resultado">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>HOLA</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>




<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#resultado tbody tr").on ("click",function (event) {
          //var value = $(this).val();
          var id= $(this).find("td:first-child").html();
          $("#txt_mostrar_num_eliminar").val(id);
      });
  });

</script>
```

Aca el formulario de la otra pagina

```
<form>
<b>ID:</b><input type="text" id="txt_mostrar_num_eliminar">
</form>
```

esto me funciona si el formulario que recibe el valor está en la misma pagina
pero cuando está en otra pagina , no me funciona.

imagen referencial del proyecto original que estoy haciendo de como se ve cuando veo los datos en un modal ubicado en la misma pagina
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá imagen referencia del proyecto original que estoy haciendo cuando intento ver los mismos datos pero en otra pagina
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
por favor si me pudiesen ayudar.
 gracias

Comment: Me podrían ayudar a ver cual es el problema por favor, no conozco mucho de javascritp, por eso les pido ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Alguien me podría ayudar por favor

Comment: Alguien me podria ayudar por favor , lo que me interesa es saber como puedo enviar los datos de una tabla html a otra pagina html usando javascript ya que usando la funcion javascript que indiqué , solo me funciona en la misma pagina pero para enviar esos datos a otra pagina, no me funciona. Por favor su ayuda.

Comment: Alguien me podria ayudar por favor , lo que me interesa es saber como puedo enviar los datos de una tabla html a otra pagina html usando javascript ya que usando la funcion javascript que indiqué , solo me funciona en la misma pagina pero para enviar esos datos a otra pagina, no me funciona. Por favor su ayuda.